# A Question on the Quotient Group and/or set of cosets

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

I'm just confused about a somewhat simple fact about quotient groups. If we have:

$$H<G/N$$ is a subgroup of the quotient of a finite group $G$ by $N\trianglelefteq G$, and $|H|=n$. Can we necessarily conclude that $G$ has a subgroup of order $n$? I'm pretty sure this is false, in general.

Do we have that $$H\cong K/N$$ for some subgroup $K\leq G$, I think this is what my professor was saying. In that case, would the order of the cooresponding subgroup $K$ have $|K|=n\cdot |N|$? So that the existence of a subgroup $H$, like this necessarily implies there is a subgroup $H\leq G$ s.t. $|K|=n\cdot |N|$? Does anything change if $N$ is not normal in $G$?

Comment: By the Lattice Isomorphism Theorem, subgroups of $G/N$ correspond with subgroups of $G$ tht contain $N$, and basically all nice properties (except maybe order) are preserved by this correspondence. So $H$ is isomorphic to $K/N$, for the corresponding subgroup $K$. 

However, if $H$ has order $n$, then this $K$ would have order $n|N|$, which is usually not equal to $n$.

Comment: If $N$ is not normal in $G$, then yes, things change. You can define a quotient group only with a normal subgroup.

Comment: It does not follow from the correspondence theorem that $G$ must have a subgroup of order $n$.  What are some counterexamples?  A sufficient condition for $G$ to have a subgroup of order $n$ is that $G/N$ have a subgroup of order $n/|N|$.

Comment: Okay, I see so order is still preserved but in a scaled-down sense relative to the order of $N$